# WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:4.0'

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am trying to run maven build with sonar on Ubuntu 10.04 version..but am getting below error. Can someone help me here what configuration I need to make..

Error is here:-

[INFO] Sonar version: 4.0
[INFO] Execute: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:4.0:sonar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/4.0/sonar-maven-plugin-4.0.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:pom:4.0' from repository central (: Error transferring file: Connection timed out
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/4.0/sonar-maven-

Comment: I assume you have the wrong version, cause the sonar-maven-plugin at codehaus has 2.2 version and not 4.0.

Comment: @khmarbaise.  There is a [4.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.sonar%7Csonar-maven-plugin%7C4.0%7Cmaven-plugin) version.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?  Connection timed out seems to indicate network issue